# STL template function to return a pair

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, templates, std-pair

I'm trying to write a function that returns a pair of values from an STL container.

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<typename T::value_type,typename T::value_type> getMinMax(T &container) {

    auto min = *(container.begin());
    auto max = *(container.begin());

    for (auto it : container) {
        if (min > (*it) ) {
            min = (*it);
        }
        if (max < (*it) ) {
            max = (*it);
        }
    }
    return std::make_pair(min, max);
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> c{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto p = getMinMax(c);
    std::cout << "min: " << p.first << " max: " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
        if (min > (*it) ) {
```

I don't know how to deal with that.

Besides that error, is there a better way to implement the desired behavior?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax

Comment: *Is there a better way to implement the desired behavior?*.  Yes, [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)

Comment: @user1211030  In this code snippet      for (auto it : container) {
        if (min > (*it) ) {
            min = (*it);
        } it is not an iterator or a pointer. It has the value type. So remove the dereferencing.

Comment: *for range* return element, not iterator

Comment: @user1211030  In general the function has undefined behavior because the container can be empty.:)

Comment: @jarod42 That's the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*for range* returns element, not iterator. So your loop should be something like:

```
for (const auto& e : container) {
    if (min > e) {
        min = e;
    }
    if (max < e) {
        max = e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<typename T::value_type, typename T::value_type> getMinMax(T &container) {

    auto min = *(container.begin());
    auto max = *(container.begin());

    for (const auto& element : container) { /* ERROR WAS HERE, FOR RANGE LOOPS RETURN AN ELEMENT */
        if (min > element) {
            min = element;
        }
        if (max < element) {
            max = element;
        }
    }
    return std::make_pair(min, max);
};
```

Hey! This should work, you were setting `min` and `max` to a dereferenced `element`, which of course, isn't what we want. :)

Also, you can get undefined behavior with this, for example, if the `container` was empty. Perhaps you should add some checks that check for that.

Comment: `std::pair` has to have values in it, it can't be empty. If the container is empty, returning a default `std::pair` would contain values that might confuse the caller as being valid when they really are not. Maybe return a `std::pair<std:::pair, bool>` instead, where the `bool` indicates success/fail (similar to `std::map::insert()`)? Otherwise, just throw an exception instead.

Comment: I didn't know this. Thank you

Comment: @Remy Lebeau If the container is empty the presented function has undefined behavior.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: yes, I know. Graham's said as much in his answer: "*you can get undefined behavior with this, for example, if the container was empty. **Perhaps you should add some checks that check for that***", to which I replied by providing ways in which the function could report to the caller that it isn't able to return a valid `std::pair` for an empty container.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function can have undefined behavior in case when the container is empty because there can be an attempt of dereferencing the iterator of an empty container.

In loops like this

```
for (auto it : container) {
    if (min > (*it) ) {
        min = (*it);
    }
```

there is incorrectly used dereferencing.

You could use the standard algorithm `std::minmax_element`. However it does not do the same as your code. It returns the first minimum element and the last maximum element. So you should rewrite the algorithm `std::minmax_element`  such a way that ir would return the first minimum element (the iterator pointing to the first minimum element) and the first maximum element (the iterator pointing to the first maximum element).

The function can be defined for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
auto getMinMax( T &container ) 
    -> std::pair<decltype( container.begin() ), decltype( container.begin() )> 
{
    auto min = container.begin();
    auto max = container.begin();

    if ( !container.empty() )
    {
        for ( auto it = container.begin(); ++it != container.end();  )
        {
            if ( *it < *min ) min = it;
            else if ( *max < *it ) max = it;
        }
    }

    return { min, max };
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 5, 2, 3, 7, 1, 4, 9, 8, 6 };

    auto minmax = getMinMax( v );

    std::cout << "Minimum = " << *minmax.first 
              << " at position " << std::distance( v.begin(), minmax.first )
              << " and maximum = " << *minmax.second
              << " at position " << std::distance( v.begin(), minmax.second )
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Minimum = 1 at position 4 and maximum = 9 at position 6
```